# In R, making a probability distribution table

Tags: r

In R, what is good way of creating a probability distribution table (that will be used for sampling)?
Say I have the following probability distribution:

```
  x   y   p(x,y)
100   0      0.5
100 100      0.1
100 200      0.1
250   0      0.1
250 100      0.1
250 200      0.1
```

Is data frame the most suitable type for this purpose? What is a simple and elegant way of creating a data frame (or another suitable structure) that contains this probability distribution?

**EDIT:**
I understand that I could simply concatenate three vectors into a data frame. I was just wondering if there is a clearer way of constructing such a table, such as (R pseudo-code):

```
p[100,0] <- 0.5
p[100,100] <- 0.1
...
```

Comment: From your edit, it seems I misunderstood your question, and you were actually asking how to construct that data frame. See my edit below. Did I answer your question now?

Answer (score 0):

That structure is fine. Here's how you'd draw 10 samples from it:

```
d[sample(1:nrow(d), 10, rep = T, prob = d$"p(x,y)"), -ncol(d)]
```

We use `rep = T` to sample with replacement.

Note that the `prob` argument need not be normalized to sum to 1. R will take care of this automatically.

**Edit replying to your edit:** You can construct the data frame above like this:

```
d = data.frame(
    x = c(100, 100, 100, 250, 250, 250),
    y = c(0,   100, 200, 0,   100, 200),
    p = c(.5, .1,  .1,   .1,  .1, .1))
```

Comment: `T` isn't "protected" and can be redefined easily and often by error. `TRUE` is much safer and only 3 extra letters.